# ConcCurrentDictionary Initialize

Tags: vb.net, concurrentdictionary

Is it possible to declare and initialize a ConcurrentDictionary? Maybe something like the Dictionary:

```
Dim Stuff = New ConcurrentDictionary(Of Integer, Integer) From {{0, 1}, {2, 3}}
```

Comment: No, a collection class must have an Add() method to allow an initializer.  ConcurrentDictionary has TryAdd().  Wanting to do this is quite strange and likely to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is something like this:

```
Dim Stuff As New ConcurrentDictionary(Of Integer, Integer) _
    ({
            New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(1, 2),
            New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(3, 4),
            New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(5, 6)})
```

ConcurrentDictionary can't use an initializer like the Dictionary since that method relies on having an Add method and ConcurrentDictionary only has AddOrUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Dictionary as an intermediate storage, and [this constructor of ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287236%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim Stuff = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) From {{0, 1}, {2, 3}}
Dim concurrentStuff = New ConcurrentDictionary(Of Integer, Integer)(Stuff)
```